# How to forward multiline docker logs using fluentd?

Tags: logging, fluentd

Following is my configuration for forwarding docker logs from `fluent.conf`, I want to add multiline parsing.

```
<source>
  @type forward
  port 24224
  bind 0.0.0.0
</source>
```

Fluentd has a multiline parser but it is only supported with `in_tail` plugin. I tried adding multiline parser with `in_tail` plugin and it worked but I am not able to add it for docker logs.

```
<parse>
    @type multiline
    format_firstline /\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}/
    format1 /^(?<logtime>\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}.\d{1,9}) \[(?<thread>.*?)]\ (?<level>[^\s]+)(?<log>.*)/
  </parse>
```

How can I add a multiline parser for docker logs with `forward` plugin on fluentd?

Comment: Hi bot,
Have you tried this documentation[1]? I don't think it is using the forward plugin but it might be of help to send docker logs.

[1] https://www.fluentd.org/guides/recipes/docker-logging

Answer (score 2):

Practically, what I've done to solve this is write the data received (from `<source>` type forward) into a file (with `<match>` type file), then read the file (with `<source>` type tail), at which point I can use multi-line parser. Metadata from original source (such as hostname, environment name, etc) has to be stored in the filename and then fished out using tag parts.

Example:

Docker daemon runs with following options:

```
--log-driver=fluentd --log-opt tag=ecs.{{.ImageName}}
```

Fluentd config is as follows:

```
<source>
  @type forward
  port 24224
</source>

<match ecs.**>
  @type forest
  subtype file
  <template>
    time_slice_format %Y-%m-%d
    path /var/log/td-agent/ecs/${tag}.*.log
    format single_value
    message_key log
    append true
  </template>
</match>

<source>
  type tail
  format multiline
  format_firstline /\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}/
  format1 /(?<time>\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}([,.]\d{1,4})*\S*)\s+(?<level>\w+)\s+\[(?<thread>.*?)\s*\]\s+(?<message>.+)/
  path /var/log/td-agent/ecs/ecs.*.java.*.log
  multiline_flush_interval 2s
  pos_file /var/log/td-agent/ecs/java-1.pos
  tag java.log-1.*
  refresh_interval 5
</source>

<match java.**>
  type elasticsearch
  host es-host
  port 9200
  index_name java
  logstash_format true
  logstash_prefix java
</match>
```

By the way, you can also include values from Docker labels in the tag that gets passed to fluentd, with Docker daemon option as follows:

```
--log-opt tag='ecs.{{.ContainerLabels.ENVIRONMENT}}.{{.ContainerLabels.LOG_TYPE}}.{{.ContainerLabels.ARTIFACT_ID}}.{{.ContainerLabels.ARTIFACT_VERSION}}.{{index .ContainerLabels \\\"spinnaker.servergroup\\\"}}'
```

In the above example, I've added 4 labels to the tag that gets passed to fluentd, which can then be extracted into fields and passed on to Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either **fluent-plugin-concat** in general or **fluent-plugin-detect-exceptions** if you need to just concatenate exception log messages.

Fluentd documentation for handling multiple lines originating from a Docker Driver is: [here](https://docs.fluentd.org/container-deployment/docker-logging-driver#additional-step-2-concatenate-multiple-lines-log-messages)

I also found the following links useful:

- [Handling multiline log for EFK stack](https://arnoldgalovics.com/java-and-spring-boot-multiline-log-support-for-fluentd-efk-stack/)
- [Deadlock error with detect_exception plugin](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/fluent-plugin-detect-exceptions/issues/19)

Finally, the following is the configuration I used in my case to get started:

```
<source>
  @type forward
  port 24224
  bind 0.0.0.0
  tag removeme.docker
</source>

<match removeme.docker.**>
  @type detect_exceptions
  message log
  remove_tag_prefix removeme
  languages java, python
  multiline_flush_interval 1
</match>

<match docker.**>
  @type copy
  <store>
    @type elasticsearch
    host elasticsearch-1
    port 9200
    logstash_format true
    logstash_prefix fluentd
    logstash_dateformat %Y%m%d
    include_tag_key true
    type_name access_log
    tag_key @log_name
    flush_interval 1s
  </store>
  <store>
    @type stdout
  </store>
</match>
```